# How to use Data Kinds + Phantom types to encode units in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, data-kinds, phantom-types

The code below **does not work** because it **does** compile. It should not (intuitively).

1) Why does this code compile ?

2) How can I "fix" this program so that "bad" programs like `isKm $ getMeter 1` is rejected during compile time ?

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs,StandaloneDeriving,DataKinds,ConstraintKinds,KindSignatures #-}

main=putStrLn "hw"

type Length (unit::LengthUnit)= Double
data LengthUnit= Km | Meter

divideByTwo ::Length lu->Length lu
divideByTwo l =l/2

getKm ::Double->Length Km
getKm d = d

getMeter ::Double->Length Meter
getMeter d =d

isKm :: Length Km ->Bool
isKm _ = True

this_should_not_compile_but_it_does=isKm $ divideByTwo $ getMeter 1

this_is_even_stranger_that_it_does_compile = isKm $ getMeter 1
```

Comment: Remember that `type` is not generative. `Length Meter = Double = Length Km`. You have not introduced any unit-based distinctions here at all, I'm afraid. You may do better with `newtype` or `data`.

Comment: Ok, so the key is that `type` is not generative, so I need to read up on what is generative and what is not :) thanks for guiding me towards the right direction.

Comment: Is this a good intro to what generative means ? http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~sweirich/papers/popl163af-weirich.pdf

Comment: No. But it's not tricky. Generative definitions make new things. Non-generative definitions make new names for old things.

Comment: Thanks :) that indeed does not sound very scary.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It compiles because `type` doesn't introduce a [new **distinct** type](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-730004.2.2):

> A type synonym declaration introduces a new type that is equivalent to an old type. 
>   [...]
>
> Type synonyms are a convenient, but strictly syntactic, mechanism to make type signatures more readable. ***A synonym and its definition are completely interchangeable,*** [...]

Completely, without restrictions, at any level, including type signatures. You can see this with an even shorter example:

```
type Clown a b = Double

proof :: Clown a b -> Clown b a
proof = id
```

Since `Clown a b` and `Clown b a` are both `Double`—regardless of the actual `a` and `b`—both can be exchanged for `Double`, and `proof`'s type is `Double -> Double`.

While your constraint limits the possible types for `a` in `Length a`, it doesn't actually change the se­man­tics of the resulting type. Instead, use a `newtype`:

```
data LengthUnit = Km | Meter
newtype Length (unit::LengthUnit) = MkLength {getLength :: Double}

onLength  :: (Double -> Double) -> Length a -> Length a
onLength f = MkLength . f . getLength

divideByTwo ::Length l -> Length l
divideByTwo = onLength (/ 2)

getKm ::Double -> Length Km
getKm = MkLength

-- other code omitted
```

Now you will get the desired compile term errors, because `Length Km` and `Length Meter` are distinct types:

```
test.hs:25:44:
    Couldn't match type 'Meter with 'Km
    Expected type: Length 'Km
      Actual type: Length 'Meter
    In the second argument of `($)', namely `divideByTwo $ getMeter 1'
    In the expression: isKm $ divideByTwo $ getMeter 1
    In an equation for `this_should_not_compile_but_it_does':
        this_should_not_compile_but_it_does
          = isKm $ divideByTwo $ getMeter 1

test.hs:27:53:
    Couldn't match type 'Meter with 'Km
    Expected type: Length 'Km
      Actual type: Length 'Meter
    In the second argument of `($)', namely `getMeter 1'
    In the expression: isKm $ getMeter 1
```

Answer (score 6):

The `type` keyword only creates an alias. For example `type Foo = Bar` just means that the compiler knows that you mean `Bar` whenever you say `Foo`. In this case this means that `Length Km` is equivalent to `Double`. The same is true for `Length Meter`. The compiler treats them both as `Double` and thus there is no difference between them.

The `Data` keyword however creates a new type rather than pointing to another one. by replacing `type Length (unit::LengthUnit)= Double` with `data Length (unit::LengthUnit)= Len Double` we create a new type which holds the `Double` within itself (constructed with `Len`).

The following code fails as desired:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs,StandaloneDeriving,DataKinds,ConstraintKinds,KindSignatures #-}

main=putStrLn "hw"

data Length (unit::LengthUnit)= LenD Double
--type Length (unit::LengthUnit)= Double
data LengthUnit= Km | Meter

divideByTwo ::Length lu->Length lu
divideByTwo (LenD l) =LenD (l/2)

getKm ::Double->Length Km
getKm d =LenD d

getMeter ::Double->Length Meter
getMeter d =LenD d

isKm :: Length Km ->Bool
isKm _ = True

this_should_not_compile_but_it_does=isKm $ divideByTwo $ getMeter 1

this_is_even_stranger_that_it_does_compile = isKm $ getMeter 1
```

The following error was given from `ghc code.hs`:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( code.hs, code.o )

code.hs:20:44:
    Couldn't match type 'Meter with 'Km
    Expected type: Length 'Km
      Actual type: Length 'Meter
    In the second argument of `($)', namely `divideByTwo $ getMeter 1'
    In the expression: isKm $ divideByTwo $ getMeter 1
    In an equation for `this_should_not_compile_but_it_does':
        this_should_not_compile_but_it_does
          = isKm $ divideByTwo $ getMeter 1

code.hs:22:53:
    Couldn't match type 'Meter with 'Km
    Expected type: Length 'Km
      Actual type: Length 'Meter
    In the return type of a call of `getMeter'
    In the second argument of `($)', namely `getMeter 1'
    In the expression: isKm $ getMeter 1
```

The error points out that we are getting `Km` and `Meter` mixed up.